# Convert number of interval into float variable

Tags: javascript, time, setinterval

I'm using javascript to record a time between to event.

So, I set an interval of 10

```
gameTimer = setInterval(incTime,10);
```

At the end, for example if I get 99 how to convert it to a float variable (0.099) ?

Comment: I don't know what the interval has to do with the question but generally to convert an integer to a thousandth of itself you divide it by 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **At the end, for example if I get 99 how to convert it to a float
>   variable (0.099) ?**

You may simply divide it by 1000. Something like this:-

```
var a = 99;
var b = 99/1000.0;
var result = b.toFixed(3); //Use this if you want to restrict the number after the decimal. Like 0.099
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript.

Comment: @Juhana:- Didnt get that! :( Did I missed something?

Comment: `var b : float` is not valid JavaScript. Some non-standard dialects that have strong typing use a syntax like that, but not standard JS.

Comment: @Juhana:- My point was to make OP realize that he can achieve what he wants by dividing 99 by 1000. I found this way. Is that wrong? Do correct me :(

Comment: @Juhana:- Does that make it better?

Comment: Yes, it's not a syntax error anymore (although the `toFixed()` is unnecessary).

Comment: @Juhana:- Yes I know that but just wanted to make it so that OP can realize that he can restrict the number after the decimal places! ;)

Comment: Thank you, in fact it was obvious, shame on me :)